# Ionic 4 is showing invalid JAVA_HOME path on apk build but it's already exists and the path exists

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I am trying to build an apk out of my ionic project. When I use both commands:

```
ionic build cordova android

ionic build cordova --release android
```

The script runs normally with no errors show, but no APK file is generated.

I tried to remove the platform and add it again, and then repeat the process using one of commands above:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android
```

And still the same.

I tried to debug the app using:

```
cordova build --release android
```

And an error appeared:

> Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin

But I checked the path and it's correct. Here is my `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` env variables:

At the PATH variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin;
```

I am using both because when I remove one of them it will ask for it.

And the JAVA_HOME:

[image]

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` should be like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`

Comment: @Mridul so no need for the `\bin` thing ?

Comment: Yes. it should work this way.

Answer (score 2):

your path is wrong it shoud be like:
**C:\Programe files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181**
if you installed JRE your JRE_HOME shoild be:
**C:\Programe files\Java\jre1.8.0_181**

Comment: without the `\bin` you mean?

Answer (score 1):

After all the configuration done, Please restart your machine. That's how I actually resolve my issue. :)